# Creating containers c++

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I'm wondering if creating my own container is very useful ? There are a few containers already implemented in c++ but what are the advantages of creating my own container ?

More information : I am a beginner.

Edit : can someone give me an example of what a Standard Library container can't do ?

Comment: If the *containers* that come with the _Standard Library_ don't suit your purposes, then you might create your own, or use a 3rd party library that provides what you want. But creating efficient containers is quite difficult and generally requires advanced techniques.

Comment: Assuming you're ready for the task, then creating your own container would be a very useful learning exercise.

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66256843/edit) your question to define, in written English, what is a container for you? See [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) ? Is it related to the `template` keyword? Perhaps your question becomes: "when are `template`-s useful in C++?"

Answer (score 3):

If your intent is to learn about the containers and C++, by all means, go ahead and try to implement them. If you just want to use a container and it exists in the standard library, boost, or some other reputable library you have in your project, just use the library version. It's likely to be well tested and optimized. Other programmers are also likely to be more familiar with that container than something you roll out yourself.

A rule of thumb is, reuse code, unless you can do better and can justify the associated cost.

Comment: note: the containers on Visual C++ seem pretty slow, but that's only if you compile your program in debug mode

Comment: @user253751 that's probably because they do bounds checking in debug builds, but that shouldn't matter for debugging anyway.

Comment: It makes people think the standard library is slow.

Comment: @user253751 everything is pretty slow in debug, thats not a disadvantage of standard containers

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn how to program, or understand how containers work, or everything related to them, then your own implementation of containers is a good practice.

However, large companies often also use their own containers, as they may consider standard containers and algorithms not optimal for their own tasks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several non-standard containers in Boost, like the ones in [Boost.Container](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html) or [Boost Graph Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html), so there's certainly some ground the STL doesn't cover.

Generally speaking, start with `std::vector` and check the other STL containers if it doesn't meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

C++ Standard Library is a general purpose library for C++ programming language. In is designed to be well enough for most tasks you may encounter in your job. But sometimes it can turn out that some container from Standard Library does not fit your needs. This is the case when you can implement your own version of some container because Standard Library can't satisfy absolutely every need that can arise during your work.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if creating my own container is very useful ?

It could be.

### My understanding of containers is `template`-s in C++ code

A simple example are matrixes. You may want to develop your own `template<unsigned Height,unsigned Width,typeclass ElementType> class Matrix`, and you would certainly call that a container. Remember that matrices of polynomial makes sense in mathematics.

A typical example is numerical scientific computations, related to representing huge mathematical [symmetrical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) or [triangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix) or diagonal or [sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) (etc...) [matrixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) on various kind of numbers (`float`-s, but also [bignums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)). Think of [finite element methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) computation.

The [opencv](https://opencv.org/) library is an open source C++ library on computer vision which uses `template`-s. Download its source code and study it.

Another example is some heavy C++ software taking advantage of [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) (when that is available).

Or representing *efficiently* in memory a [mathematical permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) between integers less than some given *N*. You may want to represent that as two `std::vector`s (one for the direct, another for the inverse mapping) inside your own `template`.

Some generic [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) libraries in C++ are heavily using templates.

The [Qt graphical toolkit](https://qt.io/) is coded in C++, is open source, and has `template`-s.

The [tensorflow](https://tensorflow.org/) machine learning library has open source C++ code with `template`-s.

The [Wt web toolkit](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) is coded in C++, is open source, and uses `template`-s. You can download and study its source code. My opinion is that it has specialized containers.

The [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler is coded mostly in C++, is free software, and uses `template`-s. You can download and study its source code.  My opinion is that it has specialized containers.

A third example is [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) support. The [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project has templates...

A fourth example could be related to storing your C++ container in a database (like [PostgreSQL](https://postgresql.org/))

Don't forget another approach: generating C++ code (like [SWIG](https://swig.org/) or [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) does) from some higher-level description. And be aware of the [rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html).

See also [Autosar MISRA C++ coding guidelines](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/adaptive/18-10/AUTOSAR_RS_CPP14Guidelines.pdf).